# Остановить сервис при удалении уведомления

Tags: android

Есть такой метод который строки уведомление

```
private void showNotify() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(MyConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Тестовый заголовок")
            .setContentText("Описание")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
    startForeground(MyConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
}
```

Метод находится в сервисе. Как сделать так, чтобы при удалении уведомления свайпом сервис останавливался?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен `setDeleteIntent()` - указываете в нем `PendingIntent`, который будет останавливать сервис

> The intent to execute when the notification is explicitly dismissed by the user, either with the "Clear All" button or by swiping it away individually. This probably shouldn't be launching an activity since several of those will be sent at the same time.

Comment: Прописал так.. но у меня уведомление не удаляется при смахивании(

Comment: причем тут это? В общем я отваливаю :)

Comment: Ну как сделать чтобы уведомление удалялось при смахивании? Флаги я убрал, все равно не закрывается

Comment: @Barmaley, при том, что уведомление фореграунд-сервиса не удаляется (про хаки пока промолчим) и `deleteIntent` он не получит.